# AngularJS, form and display JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

Here is my code:

`PizzaStore.html`:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="PizzaApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Cool pizza for everyone!</title>
        <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/App.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div>

                        <a href="#/">Home</a>
                        <a href="#confirm/">Send order</a>
            </div>
            <br />
        <div ng-view></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

`Pizzas.html`:

```
   <div id="content">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="pizza in pizzas">
            <p>{{pizza.name}}</p>
            <img src="{{pizza.src}}" />
            <div align="center" ng-if="pizza.available === true"><span ng-click="increment($index)">+</span> {{pizza.count}} <span ng-click="decrement($index)">-</span></div>
            <p style="color: red" ng-if="pizza.available === false">Unavailable</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`App.js`:

```
var PizzaApp = angular.module('PizzaApp', ['ngRoute']);

var model = [{ "name":"Pizza one", "src":"/images/1.jpg", "available": true},
         { "name":"Pizza two", "src":"/images/2.jpg", "available": true },
         { "name":"Pizza three", "src":"/images/3.jpg", "available": true},
         { "name":"Pizza four", "src":"/images/4.jpg", "available": false}];

PizzaApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'Pizzas.html',
            controller: 'pizzasController'
        })

        .when('/confirm', {
            templateUrl: 'Confirm.html',
            controller: 'confirmController'
        });
});

PizzaApp.controller('pizzasController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.pizzas = model;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.pizzas.length; i++) {
        $scope.pizzas[i].count = 0;
    }

    $scope.increment = function (index) {
        $scope.pizzas[index].count += 1;
    };

    $scope.decrement = function (index) {
        if ($scope.pizzas[index].count >0)
            $scope.pizzas[index].count -= 1;
    };
});

PizzaApp.controller('confirmController', function ($scope) {


});
```

---

It works fine, shows data, but I want to send new model from `PizzaStore.html` to `Confirm.html` (for now it's empty) in **JSON**. After that I want to display **JSON** data on that view. I've been trying to solve this problem in many ways but still can't find proper solution.

If it possible don't answer on this question like: *You can use ...*. It gonna be a lot more useful to see real solution.

---

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: If you want to share models between controllers you should look at writing an angular service to hold your model instances. Then you can inject the service into your controllers for retrieving the model you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service:

```
PizzaApp.service('orderService', [orderService]);

function orderService(){
    var _order = undefined;

    return {
        getOrder: function(){
            if(typeof _order !== 'undefined'){
                return _order;
            }
        },
        setOrder: function(order){
            _order = order;
        }
    }
}
```

Then inject the service into your controllers, and when the user clicks the confirm order, you would set the order with orderService.setOrder(order) and retrieve it on the confirm order page with orderService.getOrder()